# Send SMS with more than 160 characters using Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, sms

I tried the code mentioned in the accepted answer for [Send SMS with more than 160 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719854/send-sms-with-more-than-160-characters)

This doesn't work as expected and no text messages are sent after I tap 'Ok' in the display alert message. I couldn't find any error, not sure what happens in the background. I don't have enough reputation to comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41757318/14311349).

```cs
void TestButton_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = editTextTx.Text;            

            if (((decimal)message.Length/ 160) == message.Length / 160)
                text_i = message.Length / 160;
            else
                text_i = (message.Length / 160) + 1;

            Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            Android.App.AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
            alert.SetTitle("Warning");
            alert.SetMessage("It will need " + text_i.ToString() + " text message(s)");
            alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
            {

                var destinationAdd = "**MY NUMBER**";

                SmsManager sm = SmsManager.Default;
                if (message.Length >= 160)
                {
                    List<string> parts = new List<string>();
                    //split the message into parts of 160 chars.
                    var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, message.Length / 160).Select(i => message.Substring(i * 160, 160));
                    parts = enumerable.ToList();
                    sm.SendMultipartTextMessage(destinationAdd, null, parts, null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    sm.SendTextMessage(destinationAdd, null, message, null, null);
                }


            });
            alert.Show();
           
        }
```

It works fine for one text message which has less than 160 characters with the below code:

```cs
 try
                {

                SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("**MY NUMBER**", null, "test message", null, null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                    

                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: have you checked that `parts` contains the data that you think it does?

Comment: it says `Count=0` https://i.imgur.com/HkLowLh.png

Comment: then something is wrong with your query

Comment: @Jason yes parts has the data https://i.imgur.com/NTiaVB0.png I had used wrong breakpoint earlier

Comment: are you testing on an actual device?  does your carrier support multipart test messages?  Does it work if you send a shorter message?

Comment: Yes (One Plus 6). Yes carrier supports multipart messages. Yes it works and sends 1 part with 160 chars if I change `enumerable` in above code to `var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(i => message.Substring(i * 160, 160));`

Comment: have you tried using a value that is less than 160?

Comment: Interesting that it works for 150. And then I tried all the values between 150-160. It works for only 151,152 and 153. Not sure what is the reason. Also every message had last few characters missing. They aren't in `parts` so something to do with breaking of `message` in different parts.

Comment: `parts = [message[i:i+150] for i in range(0, len(message), 150)]` this python code breaks message string in to parts as expected with no characters missing. Will have to implement this using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Changed characters for breaking the messages into parts from 160 to 150 (Not sure why it doesn't work for anything between 153-160)

Thanks [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) for the help

- In the above code it was missing the last few characters because if you break the string in to parts there can be last part with less chars and not exactly 150. Changed the code and added a `try` and `catch` statement to get the all the characters in different parts

```cs
void TestButton_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = editTextTx.Text;            

            if (((decimal)message.Length/ 150) == message.Length / 150)
                text_i = message.Length / 150;
            else
                text_i = (message.Length / 150) + 1;

            Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            Android.App.AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
            alert.SetTitle("Warning");
            alert.SetMessage("It will need " + text_i.ToString() + " text message(s)");
            alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
            {
var destinationAdd = "MY NUMBER";

                SmsManager sm = SmsManager.Default;
                if (message.Length >= 150)
                {
                    

                    //split the message into parts of 150 chars.

                    
                    List<string> parts = new List<string>();

                    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, text_i))
                    {
                        string tword = "";
                        try
                        {
                            tword = message[(i * 150)..][..150];

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex) //to get the last few characters
                        {
                            tword = message[(i * 150)..];
                        }
                        parts.Add(tword);                 
                                                

                    };

                    sm.SendMultipartTextMessage(destinationAdd, null, parts, null, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    sm.SendTextMessage(destinationAdd, null, message, null, null);
                }
});
            alert.Show();
           
        }
```